# Is it possible to implicitly import traits when importing a type in Rust?

Tags: rust

There are some files which have been written which define a type. Some traits are implemented for this type.

When importing the type with `use TYPE_X` is it possible to implicitly import the Traits which are implemented for `TYPE_X` ?

For example, `FromStr` is a trait which requires explicitly importing `std::str::FromStr` everywhere in order to call `TYPE_X::from_str()`. This is somewhat inconvenient and in this particular case results in importing several traits just to be able to use a single type.

Comment: This is not currently possible, but there is an early stage proporsaf for `fundamental impl trait` which would allow some traits to always be usable on some types even without explicitly importing the traits.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.

The closest you can do is place (or reexport) the type and the trait from some module and glob-import from it (`use module::*`). However glob imports are generally discouraged.

Comment: Not relevant to my question, but I use glob imports for files which contain a list of `pub use` to aggregate together a large set of types which make sense to be imported as a group. `use my_lib::something::all::*`